# Need mysql remote access with my system IP

Tags: mysql

I have been using ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS and now i want to give permission of my local mysql server for my colleague system in my network. I need the answes for the following question,

1. How to bind my system IP address to mysql server. If i execute the command line "mysql -uroot -proot -h192.168.1.198", then received the error message below

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.198' (111)

2. Then how to give permission to other system user to access my local mysql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MySQL service is bound to serve localhost only (interface binding). This is the default for security reasons. If you really need to access it directly from other hosts, there is a nice How to enable remote access to MySQL on Ubuntu which you could follow:

as root, open your /etc/mysql/my.cnf with your favorite editor
look for the [mysqld] section, and in there for the bind-address keyword. This usually is set to 127.0.0.1 -- change that to match your "normal" IP-address
    save the file, and reload the service (e.g. using service mysql restart)

Remember you must enable your remote users to access their database(s) from remote, by setting the appropriate GRANTs -- e.g.

```
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO remoteuser@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'SomePASSWORD';
```

Note the @'%', which means "from any host".

Answer (score 0):

Try to telnet MySql server from that PC

```
telnet 192.168.1.198 3306
```

If that fails there are two cases:

1. You have not properly opened MySql Server required ports (default: 3306)
2. Go to my.ini (or my.cnf) and comment out `bind-address` and change it to 0.0.0.0 (to listen to all available interfaces) or perhaps the server's LAN IP (192.168.1.XYZ).